# NSComboBox - item selected action?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ibaction, nscombobox

is there an IBAction for item selection in NSComboBox?

I trying to define 2 different actions - one for item selected from the drop box, and another action for entering a new value.
is that possible?

*I'm doing a mac app, not iOS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can distinguish between the two events in your delegate, but not through an `IBAction`.  The `NSComboBoxDelegate` protocol responds to the selector `- (void)comboBoxSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification`.  You can use this to determine when an item was selected from the drop box, and use the text editing delegate selector `- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification` to determine when the user entered text directly.

Answer (score 3):

so I added this code to my **viewController.m**:

```
-(void)comboBoxSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification{
    NSLog(@"comboBoxSelectionDidChange");
}

- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
     NSLog(@"controlTextDidEndEditing");
}
```

Then, connected my combobox "*cmbbox*" to the delegate on *viewDidLoad*:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      self.cmbbox.delegate = self;
}
```

and finally, added the *NSComboBoxDelegate* delegate protocol to **viewController.h** header file:

```
@interface ViewController : NSViewController <NSComboBoxDelegate>
```